# How will Lightning Testing Service (LTS) be delivered when it is GA?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-testing-service

Took a first look at the [Lightning Testing Service (LTS)](https://github.com/forcedotcom/LightningTestingService) that is in (open) pilot today:

> The Lightning Testing Service, or LTS, is a set of tools and services
>   that let you create test suites for your Lightning components using
>   standard JavaScript test frameworks, such as Jasmine.

In its present form it is an unmanaged package meaning you have components and static resources added to your org and so your version control system.

Will the delivery mechanism change for GA? (Wondering whether if I add the components etc now I will have unused debris left in the future.)

See [What to Javascript-test in Lightning components and what not](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/177994/what-to-javascript-test-in-lightning-components-and-what-not) for some other discussion on LTS.

**PS**

LTS has been an unproductive tool for us; our hope is that the LWC testing tools are much, much better.

Comment: In TrailheaDX Salesforce have shown TLS, and from what I understand, they are thinking on how to deploy it to us. For example - I have asked why do I need to add a test file as a static resource - shouldn't it be part of the component bundle? they have answered (@TrevorBliss) that it is something that they are considering and it is good to have our input about it. So I believe that when it will be GA it will be different, but we need to offer our suggestions also for that to happen.

Comment: just use react, saves you from dealing with the arbitrary security enforcement, give you access to a huge community of resources; and frankly works way better

Answer (score 2):

LTS is a developer-focused function. I would think they will continue to manage it as an unmanaged package - easier to allow changes by developers. Numerous SFDC lab apps on AppExchange come to mind.

Comment: Prashanth, did you get this information from someone at DF18 or is this pure conjecture on your part? As an FYI, while the vast majority of SFCD Lab Apps are unmanaged packages, there are exceptions. Some of them are indeed managed packages.

Comment: Sorry - that was just an opinion at this time. That's an interesting point you make (although I could not locate managed packages at https://appexchange.salesforce.com/collection/SalesforceLabs). 
My point was more towards enabling a framework that will be used by developers, and by convention, allows more freedom.