# How to mock or configure lightning:workspaceAPI in Lightning Testing Service (LTS) tests?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, unit-test, service-cloud-console, lightning-testing-service

I have a Lightning Component that uses the [lightning:workspaceAPI](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_workspaceAPI.htm) component to detect that it is (or is not) running in the console view. I'm starting to look at setting up some [Lightning Testing Service (LTS)](https://github.com/forcedotcom/LightningTestingService) tests and am wondering what can be done to either mock or configure so that the `lightning:workspaceAPI` calls work?

In general I haven't found too much information beyond the very simple tests included in LTS itself. And this question [What to Javascript-test in Lightning components and what not](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/177994/what-to-javascript-test-in-lightning-components-and-what-not) here on this site.

*PS*

I've posted this question here https://github.com/forcedotcom/LightningTestingService/issues/52 as the [closed issue list](https://github.com/forcedotcom/LightningTestingService/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed) has a number of questions that have been answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted a reply with a couple of options for you to evaluate at,
https://github.com/forcedotcom/LightningTestingService/issues/52

Edit: Copied below by Keith C as generally link-only posts are discouraged here.

> I suppose there are 2 approaches you can evaluate,
>
> 1) Try using mocking capabilities of the Test Framework. This is
>   probably more practical as it doesn't require you change existing
>   code. For example,
>
> - Jasmine has some out of the box support via 'spyOn' which is also
>     being used [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/LightningTestingService/blob/master/lightning-component-tests/test/default/staticresources/jasmineExampleTests.resource#L151) by jasmine example.
> - In case of mocha, LTS brings in
>     sinonjs for mocking/spying which is being used [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/LightningTestingService/blob/master/lightning-component-tests/test/default/staticresources/mochaExampleTests.resource#L155) in a mocha
>     example.
>
> This [thread](https://github.com/forcedotcom/LightningTestingService/issues/19) also has some discussion about jasmine spies.
>
> In your case, I am thinking that you would spy on find(),
>   `spyOn(component, "find").and.callFake(function(cId) {..});`
> to return some sort of proxy/mock.
>
> 2) Restructure/Reorganize the components for Dependency Injection
>   where the leaf/UI components mostly act based on information provided
>   to them by a wrapper/container, improving their testability.