# Is is possible to spyOn a helper function in a Lightning Testing Service (LTS) test?

Tags: lightning-testing-service, jasmine

In [How to mock or configure lightning:workspaceAPI in Lightning Testing Service (LTS) tests?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/204676/how-to-mock-or-configure-lightningworkspaceapi-in-lightning-testing-service-lt) the answer suggests using Jasmine's `spyOn` to call a fake function in a test and so work-around an API that isn't present in the LTS context.

From Googling I don't see a (supported) way to access the helper functions so using `spyOn` to fake there doesn't look possible. So I'm thinking that I'm going to have to move an inherited function from the helper to the controller to use `spyOn`. Is that correct?

*PS*

To save changing quite a lot of code I have added this as an equivalent of the Apex [Test.isRunningTest](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000205831&type=1) for now (where $T is added by LTS):

```
    if (typeof $T !== "undefined") {
        // LTS version of code
    } else {
        // Production versions of code
    }
```